# How to import log file to Matomo?

Tags: matomo, piwiktracker

I'm trying to import the log files to Matomo but really much help from the read-me file or in the tutorial. Based on information provided i have tried below command but getting error.

```
 D:\Projects\temp>python C:\xampp\htdocs\analystics\misc\log-analytics\import_logs.py --url=https://test.com/analytics/index.php --user=admin --password=admin --idsite=6 daily.2019-04-10-0.log
2019-04-16 19:18:32,811: [INFO] Error when connecting to Matomo: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>
2019-04-16 19:18:32,811: [INFO] Retrying request, attempt number 2
2019-04-16 19:18:42,826: [INFO] Error when connecting to Matomo: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>
2019-04-16 19:18:42,842: [INFO] Retrying request, attempt number 3
2019-04-16 19:18:52,858: [INFO] Error when connecting to Matomo: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>
2019-04-16 19:18:52,858: [INFO] Max number of attempts reached, server is unreachable!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\analystics\misc\log-analytics\import_logs.py", line 2614, in <module>
    resolver = config.get_resolver()
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\analystics\misc\log-analytics\import_logs.py", line 1079, in get_resolver
    return StaticResolver(self.options.site_id)
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\analystics\misc\log-analytics\import_logs.py", line 1603, in __init__
    'SitesManager.getSiteFromId', idSite=self.site_id
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\analystics\misc\log-analytics\import_logs.py", line 1586, in call_api
    return cls._call_wrapper(cls._call_api, None, None, method, **kwargs)
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\analystics\misc\log-analytics\import_logs.py", line 1573, in _call_wrapper
    raise Matomo.Error(message, code)
__main__.Error: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Actually link https://test.com/analytics/index.php is working from browser, so obviously Matomo is up & running.

Comment: It seems like your webserver can't resolve the domain of your Matomo instance. What happens if you try to curl `https://test.com/analytics/index.php` on the server?

Comment: Thanks for reply. displaying html/javascript codes.

Answer (score 0):

I have added host name in the host file to run the import command. host file would be C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host